How to use a dataview.DataViewSpinRenderer in data.DataViewCtrl
I'm having trouble to use a DataViewSpinRenderer in a DataViewCtrl.
Below is the simplest example I could come up with to demonstrate the issue.
I would expect the 2nd column to display a spincontrol like this:

However, only the value is displayed (as a string).
Trying to edit the cell by double clicking will display a string like "<wxCustomRendererObject: 0x11a80b320>".

How can I get this to work?
If I want to add a SpinCtrlDouble for a 3rd column, do I need to create a DataViewCustomRenderer? How can I display the SpinCtrlDouble? The examples I've seen seem to call drawing methods themselves rather than draw wxWidget.

import wx
import wx.dataview as dv


class MyDataModel(dv.PyDataViewModel):
    def __init__(self):
        dv.PyDataViewModel.__init__(self)
        self.data = [["apples", 1], ["oranges", 2], ["pineapples", 3]]

    def IsContainer(self, item):
        return False

    def GetChildren(self, parent, children):
        if not parent:
            for v in self.data:
                children.append(self.ObjectToItem(v))
            return len(self.data)
        return 0

    def GetColumnCount(self):
        return 2

    def GetValue(self, item, col):
        obj = self.ItemToObject(item)
        v = obj[col]

        print(f"returning {v}")
        return v

    def SetValue(self, value, item, col):
        print(f"Set Value col: {col}, value: {value}")
        obj = self.ItemToObject(item)
        obj[col] = value
        return True


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "DataView")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        dvc = dv.DataViewCtrl(
            panel,
            style=wx.BORDER_THEME
            | dv.DV_ROW_LINES
            | dv.DV_HORIZ_RULES
            | dv.DV_VERT_RULES
            | dv.DV_SINGLE,
            size=(600, 800),
        )
        model = MyDataModel()
        dvc.AssociateModel(model)

        dvc.AppendTextColumn(
            "Item Name",
            0,
            mode=dv.DATAVIEW_CELL_EDITABLE,
            width=-1,
            align=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT,
        )
        spin_renderer = dv.DataViewSpinRenderer(min=0, max=100)
        col = dv.DataViewColumn(
            "Amount",
            spin_renderer,
            1,
        )
        dvc.AppendColumn(col)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(dvc)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Layout()


app = wx.App(0)
frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()


I'm using:

wxPython 4.2.1
Python 3.11.2
Mac OS 14.3.1

